# How to access mysql database from remote system having different ip series

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, remote-access

My MySQL server is installed in X.X.60.X and accessing it through JDBC from X.X.80.X . I can connect it through MySQL workbench but when connect through the program it shows the following error message.

**`java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user'@'X.X.80.X' (using password: NO).`**

I have given all privileges to 'user'@'X.X.80.X in the server.

Comment: Does it work from command line? e.g. `mysql -h X.X.60.X -u user dbname`?

Comment: Thanks ... its mys mistake i didn't given = sysmbol after password...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the password for user 'user' set in you MySQL server? If yes, check your programm, is's not using password:`(using password: NO)`